# как увеличить число, факториал которого мы находим

Tags: циклы, pascalabc.net

есть задание [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

число, факториал которого мы находим, увеличивается каждый раз на 2. как это реализовать в паскале?
вот код:

```
const n = 3;
const f = 6;
var a, sin_a, sin_a1: real;
factorial,factorial1: longint;
i,i1: byte;
begin
  write('введите а: ');
  readln(a);
  factorial:= 1;
  factorial1:= 1;
  for i := 2 to n do
    factorial:= factorial * i;
  for i1:= 2 to n1 do
    factorial1:= factorial1 * i1;
  sin_a:=a-((power(a,n)/factorial)+(power(a,n+2)/factorial+2));
  sin_a1:= power(a,n+2)/factorial+2;
  writeln('результат = ',sin_a);
  writeln(sin_a1);
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f := a;
sin_a := f;
for i := 1 to ... begin
   f := - f * a * a / (2*i*(2*i+1));
   sin_a := sin_a + f; 
end;
```

Comment: спасибо большое!